# is the NNO in a sheaf topos a model of classical PA?

Tags: logic, topos-theory, intuitionistic-logic, categorical-logic

In their book *Models for Smooth Infinitesimal Analysis* Moerdijk and Reyes claim that the natural number object in any Grothendieck topos is a model of all classical provable statements of first order Peano arithmetic. Is this true? They do not provide a proof other than "do an induction on the formula". The semantic is the forcing semantic (equivalently the standard categorical semantic).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes.

In general, consider a Boolean topos $T$ and a topos $S$, and suppose we have a functor $F : T \to S$ which preserves finite limits and has a right adjoint (in other words, is the left part of a geometric morphism).

Even without the assumption that $T$ is Boolean, we see that $F$ is a coherent functor. This means that $F$ preserves finite limits, finite joins, and images. In other words, $F$ preserves the fragment of the internal logic consisting of $\top, \bot, \land, \lor$, $=$, and $\exists x \in A$. This is fairly easy to verify.

When we add in the assumption that $T$ is Boolean, it turns out that $F$ is also a Heyting functor. This means that $F$ also preserves the Heyting implication and dual images. So $F$ preserves the full $\Delta_0$ logic of $T$- that is, the full logic where we can quantify over elements.

Now, we may observe that given any cocomplete topos $S$, the functor $\Delta : Set \to S$ preserves finite limits and has a right adjoint - namely, the global sections functor $Hom(1, -)$. Recall that we may define $\Delta S = \coprod\limits_{s \in S} 1$.

In particular, note that $\Delta \mathbb{N}$ is the natural numbers object in $S$ (and of course the operations $0, 1, +, \cdot, succ$ are preserved by the functor). Therefore, for all sentences $\phi$ in the language of PA, if $\mathbb{N} \models \phi$ holds in the category of sets, then we also have $\Delta \mathbb{N} \models \phi$ in $S$. So in a sense, the arithmetic of $\mathbb{N}$ is absolute along the inclusion $\Delta : Set \to S$.

In fact, the left part of a geometric morphism must always preserve well-founded relations. This gives us a nice way of showing that $\Delta \mathbb{N}$ is the NNO. This is because an NNO can be axiomatised in the internal logic by the second-order Peano axioms (in Heyting arithmetic), which consist of first-order coherent axioms and the axiom that the relation $R = \{(x, succ(x)) \mid x \in \mathbb{N}\}$ is well-founded. All of these axioms are therefore preserved by $\Delta$ (even if $Set$ isn’t Boolean).

Finally, note the assumption of excluded middle for $Set$ is critical. For we could instead consider a model of constructive set theory in which Church’s thesis holds, which contradicts Peano arithmetic. But then we could take any Boolean Grothendieck topos $T$ (in particular, the double negation sheaves on $Set$ work nicely), and the functor $\Delta : Set \to T$ would be the left part of a geometric morphism but wouldn’t preserve $Set$’s arithmetic, since Peano arithmetic holds in $T$.

Comment: Oh, thanks a lot. This is a very detailed answer (and one I couldn't have come up with, because I understand not enough about geometric morphisms). Thanks!

Comment: @Nico You’re welcome! I first tried to prove things with induction on formulas, which works but is very ugly. This approach is significantly more general. It is useful, for instance, in showing that an ordinal $\alpha$ is sent to an “ordinal object” $\Delta \alpha$ in the resulting topos (ordinal object really meaning something which is a well-ordered set in the forcing semantics) - the total order structure is preserved since $\Delta$ is a Heyting functor, and the well-foundedness is also preserved. $\Delta$ is analogous to the inclusion map in normal forcing.

Comment: okay, now i understand more! :) how can i see that a geometric morphism $f: \mathcal E \to \mathcal B$ to a boolean topos is open?